# How to get through security error pages in firefox browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I'm aware that we use `thisisunsafe` in Chrome to bypass such error pages but how can I bypass such pages in Firefox?
I get the following error when I load the page:-

```
Firefox detected a potential security threat and did not continue to <site> because this website requires a secure connection.

<site> has a security policy called HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS), which means that Firefox can only connect to it securely. You can’t add an exception to visit this site.
```

I tried the following steps to resolve it but it didn't solve the issue:-

1. Opened a new tab and entered `about:config`
2. Clicked on `Accept the Risk and Continue`
3. In the search field, type in `security.enterprise_roots.enabled` and hit enter
4. I saw one field which was already enabled `true`
5. Didn't know what to do next as the field was already enabled `true`

I'm looking for a workaround of `thisisunsafe` in Firefox.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. In the Mozilla Firefox address bar, type `about:config`
2. Look for `network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist`
3. And set the last field Value to `false` and restart the browser.

Comment: No longer working in Firefox 95.02

Comment: Didn't work in 99.0.1 either

Comment: Working for Version 98.0.2 @FiddlingAway

Comment: @NehaChaudhary Nice, it seems that they've fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out, I'd completely given up on this.

Comment: If it doesn't work try: about:config in Firefox and change the security.enterprise_roots.enabled option from TRUE to FALSE.

Answer (score 24):

As of **April 5th, 2022**, this is how I bypass the `You can’t add an exception to visit this site.` with Firefox 98.

If you see this without the `Add Exception` button :

[image]

1. Open the `Preferences` of Firefox:

[image]

2. Open the `Privacy & Security` tab:

[image]

3. Scroll down to `Certificates` and click on `View Certificates...`

[image]

4. Open the `Servers` tab and click on `Add Exception...`

[image]

5. Fill in the `Location` field and click on `Get Certificate`:

[image]

6. Click on `Confirm Security Exception`:

[image]

7. You should now see your exception, click on `Ok`:

[image]

8. Reload your page and you should now be able to see your website :)

Comment: v 101.0, localhost, not working :(

Comment: Doesn't work in Fx 116, still the same error page appears.

Comment: Why does this happen on some wifi networks but not others? Is there some type of Firewall trying to do HTTPS filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Just open "about:config" and change "network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist" to "false".

That works even without restarting firefox.

Comment: This is the same suggestion as the accepted answer. Please don’t repeat answers.

Answer (score 0):

About changing the network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist value, restarting the browser may not be enough; in my case I had to manually clear the cache for it to work.